# Handling errors of customSanitizer of express-validator?

Tags: express, express-validator

I am using `express-validator` for server-side validation. I am receiving a `multipart/form-data` from. So for this, I am using `formidable`.

So I created a middleware `handleFormData` which parses the form and attaches the field values to `req.body` object.

```
exports.handleFormData = (req,res,next)=>{
    const form = formidable({ multiples: true });
    form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
        if(err){
            return res.status(500).json({
                status: false,
                error: "Unable to process request. Try again"
            })
        }
        req.body = fields
        if(files.file){
            req.body.file = files.file
        }else{
            req.body.file = {name:""}
        }
        next()
    });
}
```

Now in the form, I have a field `tags` which will be an array of string. So I will be receiving that array as `JSON string` from the frontend. Before validating I want to convert it from `JSON string` to `array`. For that, I am using a `customSanitizer`. Now my question is from the frontend if I receive an invalid `JSON string` `JSON.parse` will fail to parse. How to handle that error.

```
check("tags")
    .customSanitizer(value => {
        try {
            return JSON.parse(value); // If value was invalid then JSON.parse will fail.
        } catch (error) {
            throw new Error("Invalid Tags")
        }
    })
    .custom((values,{req})=>{
        return tags.length > 0
    })
```

So I tried using `try catch`. If `JSON.parse` fails catch block is throwing an error in the `console` only but I want to return that error as response to `user`